# RTT and bandwith allocation

Tags: bandwidth, networking

I have a doubt about RTT. I would like to know if RTT is related and how (if yes) it is related to the bandwidth allocation in case of congestion

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these two pages: [link1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-trip_delay_time) and [link2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_avoidance_algorithm) from wikipedia.

In case of a protocol that uses congestion control like TCP, the RTT should affect the congestion control algorithm.

In the second link, you can read (from "TCP Tahoe and Reno" section):

```
It starts with a window of two times the maximum segment size (MSS).
Although the initial rate is low, the rate of increase is very rapid: for every packet acknowledged,
the congestion window increases by 1 MSS so that the congestion window effectively doubles for every round trip time (RTT).
```